# JavaFX Transition animation waiting

Tags: animation, javafx, transition, command-pattern, graph-drawing

so quicky, I am doing program which demonstrate methods used for computer graph drawing. I need to create timeline or history of actions like ( placeVertex(x,y), moveVertex(newX,newY) etc. ) and iterate through (forward and backwards, automatically or manual)

I already achieved that by using command design pattern but few of these commands are using transitions. First idea was to use Condition interface's lock, await and signal in `setOnFinished` between each commands but it led to gui freezing.

I tryed SequentialTransition but it's no use for my problem - can't change properties dynamically between transitions.

Is there a possibility to somehow inform generation that one transition ended and next can run without GUI freezing and drawing?

Thanks!

edit: I ll try to simplify it all
Here is my Command interface and one of these commands:

```
 public interface Command {
        public void execute();
  }

 public class MoveVertex implements Command {
        public MoveVertex(Data d, Vertex v, double changedX, double changedY){..};

        @Override
        public void execute() {         
            Path path = new Path();         
            path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(v.getCenterX(), v.getCenterY()));
            path.getElements().add(new LineTo(changedX, changedY));

            PathTransition pathTransition = new PathTransition();   
            pathTransition.setDuration(Duration.millis(velocity)); 
            pathTransition.setPath(path);   
            pathTransition.setNode(v.getVertex());

            pathTransition.play();  }
  }
```

These Commands are stored in my history class which is basically

```
private List<Command> history;
```

And I do going through the list and executing Commands

```
public boolean executeNext() {
    if (history.size() != position) {
        history.get(position).execute();
        position++;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And I am trying to achieve state when next Command is started only if previous finished. Tryed to put await/signal in between without success.

Comment: Didn't [Transition's onFinsihedProperty()](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/Animation.html#onFinishedProperty%28%29) work for you?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha not really, for example i have one circle, two path transitions, first one move circle from 0 0 to 100 100, second one move same circle somewhere else, i do want to update location depending on first move but even if i put new `MoveTo` locations into `onFinishedProperty()` its doesn't work, probably because transition is already created from before?

Comment: That is kind of odd that onFinished is not working for you, can you include an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question which replicates the issue?  Using event handlers/property listeners that action callbacks on relevant events is the correct solution, using things which pause or sleep the JavaFX application thread is the wrong solution.

Comment: @jewelsea Hello, added few line of code. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution below uses Itachi's suggestion of providing an [onFinished](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/Animation.html#onFinishedProperty%28%29) handler to move to a node to a new (random) location after we get to the next location.

It could probably be made more efficient (and simpler to understand) by re-using a single Transition rather than using recursion within the event handler.  It is probably unnecessary to create a new Transition for each movement - but, as long as there aren't hundreds of thousands of movement iterations, it should be acceptable as is.

```
import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.util.Random;

// animates moving a node forever in a random walk pattern.
public class RandomWalk extends Application {

    private static final Random random = new Random(42);

    private static final double W = 200;
    private static final double H = 200;
    private static final double R = 10;

    private static final Node node = new Circle(
            R, Color.FORESTGREEN
    );

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        // start from the center of the screen.
        node.relocate(W / 2 - R, H / 2 - R);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(new Pane(node), W, H));
        stage.show();

        walk();
    }

    // start walking from the current position to random points in sequence.
    private void walk() {
        final Point2D to = getRandomPoint();
        final Transition transition = createMovementTransition(
                node,
                to
        );

        transition.setOnFinished(
                walkFrom(to)
        );
        transition.play();
    }

    private EventHandler<ActionEvent> walkFrom(final Point2D from) {
        return event -> {
            // Finished handler might be called a frame before transition complete,
            // leading to glitches if we relocate in the handler.
            // The transition works by manipulating translation values,
            // so zero the translation out before relocating the node.
            node.setTranslateX(0);
            node.setTranslateY(0);

            // After the transition is complete, move the node to the new location.
            // Relocation co-ordinates are adjusted by the circle's radius.
            // For a standard node, the R adjustment would be unnecessary 
            // as most nodes are located at the top left corner of the node 
            // rather than at the center like a circle is.
            node.relocate(
                    from.getX() - R,
                    from.getY() - R
            );

            // Generate the next random point and play a transition to walk to it.
            // I'd rather not use recursion here as if you recurse long enough,
            // then you will end up with a stack overflow, but I'm not quite sure
            // how to do this without recursion.
            final Point2D next = getRandomPoint();
            final Transition transition = createMovementTransition(node, next);
            transition.setOnFinished(walkFrom(next));
            transition.play();
        };
    }

    // We use a PathTransition to move from the current position to the next.
    // For the simple straight-line movement we are doing,
    // a straight TranslateTransition would have been fine.
    // A PathTransition is just used to demonstrate that this
    // can work for the generic path case, not just straight line movement.
    private Transition createMovementTransition(Node node, Point2D to) {
        Path path = new Path(
                new MoveTo(
                        0,
                        0
                ),
                new LineTo(
                        to.getX() - node.getLayoutX(),
                        to.getY() - node.getLayoutY()
                )
        );

        return new PathTransition(
                Duration.seconds(2),
                path,
                node
        );
    }

    // @return a random location within a bounding rectangle (0, 0, W, H)
    // with a margin of R kept between the point and the bounding rectangle edge.
    private Point2D getRandomPoint() {
        return new Point2D(
                random.nextInt((int) (W - 2*R)) + R,
                random.nextInt((int) (H - 2*R)) + R
        );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for solution, unfortunately for me i had to leave town for two days so i will try it later! Ill do as soon as possible and then let you know how it works. I was also thinking about recursion so I am curious. The only issue I see is pausing in the middle of generation and then finding the point where it ended (somwhere in long recursion sometimes maybe) so.. we ll see