# Chain multiple transitions

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I have a little problem concerning JavaFX. I'm currently doing a User Interface for the ants algorithm.

I would like to chain multiple `TranslateTransition` in a loop. The problem is that only one of these transitions is displayed instead of all `TranslateTransition` in the order of creation.

```
while(condition){
   //some updates...
   TranslateTransition tt = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(2000), myObject);
   tt.play();
}
```

Is there a way to make sure that previous animations are finished before playing new ones ?
Thank you !

Comment: This question is somewhat related: [JavaFX Transition animation waiting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28093416/javafx-transition-animation-waiting), that question asks: "I need to create timeline or history of actions like ( placeVertex(x,y), moveVertex(newX,newY) etc. ) and iterate through (forward and backwards, automatically or manual)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `onFinished` handler to launch the next transition. Define a method:

```
private TranslateTransition createNextTransition(Node myObject) {
    // some updates...
    TranslateTransition tt = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(2000), myObject);
    tt.setOnFinished(e -> {
        if (condition) {
            createNextTransition(myObject);
        }
    });
    tt.play();
}
```

And then just call it once:

```
createNextTransition(myObject);
```